# Error while trying to locate Web Elements with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I'm trying to use Selenium Webdriver but I'm running into some problems with my code.

I gave the page time to load but still I can't seem to find the elements.
I thought that the page might be blocking it but I tried twitter as well and It didn't work (one friend of mine said that he did something with twitter and it worked) so I don't know.

Its my first time using Selenium I thought it would be easier but no. I also changed the way that selenium goes and gets the web elements but none of them fixed it!

Chrome version: 119.0.6045.124
Selenium : 4.10.0

I have this imports (related to selenium):

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

These are the driver configurations:

```
options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
        options.add_argument('--disable-site-isolation-trials')
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= options)
        driver.get(pageurl)
```

And I have this code block:

```
anchor_url = "https://www.recaptcha.net/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LeMGXkUAAAAAOlMpEUm2UOldiq38QgBPJz5-Q-7&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9pbnRlcm5hbC1hcGkucHJvbGlmaWMuY286NDQz&hl=fr&v=gWN_U6xTIPevg0vuq7g1hct0&size=invisible&cb=igv4yino6y0f"
            reCaptcha_response = reCaptchaV3(anchor_url)
            end = time()
            print(f"Captcha solved in {end-start}s")
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
            try:
                print("trying go find username")
                username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/input"))) 
                print("found it")
                username.send_keys({config["mail"]})
            except:
                driver.quit()
            password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/input")
            captcha = driver.find_element(By.ID, "g-recaptcha-response-100000")
            password.send_keys({config["password"]})
            captcha.send_keys(reCaptcha_response)
            print("\n Done email, password and captcha")
            driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response-100000").innerHTML="{reCaptcha_response}";')
            driver.find_element(By.ID, "login").submit()
            print(sleep)
            sleep(3)
```

The error that I'm getting is this one:

```
File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1286, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1332, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1281, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 1041, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\http\client.py", line 979, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000224A968F150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Prolific-Joiner-main\Prolific-Joiner-main\my.py", line 189, in <module>
    p_updater = ProlificUpdater()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Prolific-Joiner-main\Prolific-Joiner-main\my.py", line 30, in __init__
    else: self.bearer = "Bearer " + self.get_bearer_token()
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Prolific-Joiner-main\Prolific-Joiner-main\my.py", line 95, in get_bearer_token
    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/input")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 738, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 342, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 297, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 318, in _request
    response = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 81, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\request.py", line 173, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 827, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 827, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 827, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 799, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vasco\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=52215): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/c36d583758b90867677dc53fef46febf/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000224A968F150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Its my first time using Selenium and I've dealt with bugs from not finding the elements in page and I understood that I need to let the page load in the driver. I also changed the way that selenium goes and gets the web elements but none work!

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should attempt to reproduce the error you get. Also be mindful of your indentation, the 'code block' has every line after the first indented twice for no reason, presumably. Tracebacks are usually easier to read if you also format those as code.

Comment: In the code the indentations are fine, the little indentation offset and vscode makes a big red marker. When you say tracebakcs are easier to read if I format those as code, do you mean inserting it here has a code block as well?

Comment: yes, the code block formatting helps with readability of error text.

Comment: Include version of Selenium, Chromedriver and Chrome used.   You might need options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*");

Comment: Already made the Tracebacks as a codeblock. About the versions, chrome and selenium are already up there but the chrome webdriver I can't tell. I've downloaded it and I have it in the same folder but it never asked me for a path or anything like it!
Since I had this inside the webdriver "ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()" I thought it was installing or using the webdriver.